# Show username from Nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have a login system in my website and I want to show the name of the user in the frontend using `AngularJS`, but I don't know how to pass the `user` from `NodeJS`

```
app.get('/main', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){

    res.render('main.ejs', {
        user : req.user 
    });

});
```

Comment: If you have the `user` in the front end, hence, `req.user`. Then why would you need to respond with the `req.user`, you already have that information on your client, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the snippet you provided.

Your incoming data is already the `user` you wish to display.

**In ExpressJS:**

> `req` stands for the Request, coming in from the Client.
>
> `res` stands for the Response, going back to the Client.

Good article on ExpressJS [Here](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/10/express-js-middleware-demystified/), it goes a bit more in-depth.

If your goal is to contact the `DB` when you receive a username and password from the client, then display back the user's full name. Then do something like this.

**Client (AngularJS)**

```
app.service('SomeService', ['$http',  function ($http, ) {

    this.loginUser = function(user, pass) {
        var model = {
            user: user,
            pass: pass
        };

        var promise = $http.post('/Account/Login', JSON.stringify(model))
            .then(function(response) {
                return {
                    response.fullName
                };

            }, function() {
                  //Error
                };
            });

        return promise;
    };

}]);
```

**On your Server**

```
app.get('/Account/Login', function(req, res) {
    
   //Do Logic magic here....

    return res.json({ fullName: 'John Doe'});
});
```

**Finally your Controller and HTML**

After doing the round trip, your JS Promise will be returned to the original caller of the Angular Service and you can populate a $scope variable then display it however you wish. Take a look:

```
app.controller("MyController", function('SomeService'){

$scope.fullName = '';

SomeService.loginUser ('userCool','password123')
            .then(function (response) {
                 $scope.fullName = response.fullName;
                }, function () {
                    //Some Error, Server did not respond...
            });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
   <label ng-bind="fullName"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, set it up on **server side**:

```
app.get('/api/:paramID1/:paramID2', function(req, res) {
    return res.json({ user: 'example' });
});
```

On the **client side** you need an ajax call to invoke the service like:

```
$http.get( "/api/1/abc").success(function(data) {
   $scope.user = data;
});
```